# Finding the class rank of a student from results of whole class

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I haven't learnt how to do this in my maths classes since we're starting probability in a couple months but I need to determine my rank within my cohort for chemistry.

The cohort consists of ~50 students and the highest mark was 93/100. The top 25% of the cohort got 77+/100 and 50% was 69+/100, if I got 83/100, how would I determine what rank I could possibly be among the 50 students?

(Again, sorry I can't attempt this myself since I haven't learnt anything to do with probability at all yet).

Thanks

Comment: You're strictly in the top $25$%, and your score is not the highest score.That's about all you can say.

Answer (score 0):

@quasi has already given you the most direct answer possible.

Here is a little additional terminology that may be useful answering
such questions in the future.

A *five-number summary* of a dataset consists of the minimum, lower quartile $Q_1$,
median (third quartile, sometimes denoted $H$ or $Q_2$), upper quartile $X_3$, and maximum.

Roughly speaking, 25% of the observations in the sample lie below $Q_1$,
50% below $Q_2$ and 75% below $Q_3.$ With 'about $n=50$' students it may not
be possible to find three values that partition the sorted data into
four subsets of size precisely $n/4$. Also, tied observations can cause
difficulty in finding the quartiles.

Each textbook and statistical software
package has its own rules for making the necessary compromises. However,
the differences among these rules become relatively unimportant for large $n$.

Below is how R statistical software finds the five number summary (plus the
sample mean) for a contrived dataset `x` of size $n = 50$ that roughly matches your
specifications. (Numbers in brackets are the indexes of the first observation
on each line.)

```
x
 [1] 13 13 17 21 21 22 24 25 30 31 35 38 40 41 44 47 47 53 55 58 60 60 62 66 69
[26] 69 70 70 72 73 73 74 74 75 75 75 76 77 77 80 83 89 89 90 91 92 92 93 94 98
length(x)
## 50
summary(x)
##   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##  13.00   40.25   69.00   60.26   76.75   98.00
```

You can google such phrases as `five number summary`, `quantile`, and
`descriptive statistics` to learn more. (But the current Wikipedia draft on
'five number summary' gives computer code without output; perhaps it is under construction.)